# Unable to find or serve resource

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, primefaces, glassfish-4

I am making a webapplication with Java EE 6 and Primefaces on a Glassfish 4 server. I keep getting the same annoying error more and more often. I have tried to Google this problem, but I hav not yet found a solution that works. Sometimes the application will perform with no problems at all, but then suddenly this same error occurs over and over again. This is my Stack trace:

```
    WARNING:   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, charts/charts.js, from library, primefaces.
WARNING:   java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Exceptions.makeIOException(Exceptions.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:958)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:682)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:343)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:99)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:258)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:951)
    ... 36 more
```

The same error will occur several times, but then being unable to serve resources like: jquery/jquery-plugins.js, layout/layout.js, jquery/jquery.js, primefaces.js. All from Primefaces library.

This error have been bugging me for quite some time, and answers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely a bug with grizzly framework.

**Possible causing bug:** https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20681?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

In that Jira, there is a `jar` patch. Copy to `modules` directory, clear the OSGI cache (delete glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache) and restart. This worked for me.

Also see: [GF4 incorrect timeout exception thrown in Servlet when multiple large responses are returned (requested)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881908/gf4-incorrect-timeout-exeption-thrown-in-servlet-when-multiple-large-responses-a)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the client gets resources from the server as HTTP GET requests. This means that for each CSS, JS or HTML file, you get an HTTP request.

Open you browser web console and click on network. Then go to any site and you will see how many requests you get.

Here are some suggestions regarding your problem.

1. Try to increase the Maximum Pool Size of your server. Read here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24936/tuning-glassfish.htm#abeea -> tuning the EJB Pool Settings
2. Try to analyse your web app and see if there are too many requests for the same resource. You can do this in you browser as mentioned above.
3. Analyse your JSPs for useless imports, includes or iFrames

I hope this helps

Comment: So far it seem like I solved my problem. I removed Primefaces 3.5.jar from my library and replaced it with Primefaces 3.4.2.jar and now everything seems to work... Does anyone else have problems with Primefaces 3.5?